# regular expression to skip protocol url

Tags: regex

I'm trying to define a regular expression in C# that when given a url will return the url except the protocol, such as http. That is, I need to skip any protocol and only return the domain and path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `(?<=://).+`

or

use this regex `://(.+)` *without lookbehind, value in regexGroup[1]*

Answer (score 2):

Try with following regex:

```
^[a-z]+://(.*)$


string input = "http://www.google.com/search";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[a-z]+://(.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    string url = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make group0 the non protocol part?

Comment: Sure, just use `()`: `^([a-z]+)://(.*)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple replace

```
string url = "http://url.com";
        if(url.Contains("http://")){
            url = url.Replace("http://","");
        }
        else if(url.Contains("https://")){
            url = url.Replace("https://","");
        }
```

or

```
url = Regex.Replace(url,@"[a-z]+://","");
```